# Select everything after truncating multiple values from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have records in a table address

```
6321  24TH AVE APT2 
2232 S ALLIS ST LOT 4
824 JENIFER ST Unit 2
```

I want to truncate and select everything before 'APT' , 'LOT', 'UNIT' in one substring query

I have tried

```
select SUBSTRING([ADDR1],0,CHARINDEX(' APT',[ADDR1]))
from Address
```

which only selects everything before APT but not 'LOT' , 'UNIT'

```
select SUBSTRING([ADDR1],0,CHARINDEX(' APT',[ADDR1]), CHARINDEX( 'LOT',[Addr1]),CHARINDEX( 'Unit',[Addr1]))
from Address
```

but query failed

**Tried Union**

```
select SUBSTRING([ADDR1],0,CHARINDEX(' APT',[ADDR1])) from Address
Union
select SUBSTRING([ADDR1],0,CHARINDEX(' LOT',[ADDR1])) from Address
```

but have other values suite, trailer, trlr similar to add so with volume of data I am not considering multiple UNIONS

Desired Result

```
6321 24TH AVE
2232 S ALLIS ST
824 JENIFER ST
```

Comment: What is your desired result?   What is wrong with the code you tried?   What does "but have lot of values similar to add." have to do with your question?

Comment: Please post DDL+DML+(as @TabAlleman asked) the desired result according to the DML

Comment: Oh... for these who not familiar with the phrases DDL/DML the request is to provide queries to create the table and elements like indexes (DDL), and queries to insert some sample data (DML)

Comment: I mean it's obvious the charindex with only select before everything so I didn't put desired result but I wanted to add multiple values like LOT, UNIT, Trailer, SUITE to same charidex

Comment: What is the expected result for "666 Apteryx Way"? "42 1/2 Lottie St SW"?

Comment: so each line is one value (single input) ? is this a single value which you want to parse for example or several columns in table `6321  24TH AVE APT2 ` ?

Comment: @Hanu So what is the question?   It sounds like a simple matter of typing.  If you want to add Trailer and SUITE, you have to type them into your code.   the computer is not going to read your mind.

Comment: I have updated question so it's clear and thanks for all the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `apply` if values really not large :

```
select distinct a.[ADDR1], substring(a.[ADDR1], 0, aa.lens)
from address a cross apply
     ( values ( (CHARINDEX('APT', [ADDR1])), 
                (CHARINDEX('LOT', [ADDR1])),
                (CHARINDEX('Unit', [ADDR1]),
                 . . . . . . . . . . . . . -- more filter as you want
              )
     ) aa(lens)
where aa.lens > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but not working for 'LOT' it's giving blank result

Comment: Still error at aa.[ADDR1] we didn't define .[ADDR1] for aa and invalid length passed to substring

Comment: @Hanu. . Wrong alias declared.

Comment: Nope still only first value is being truncated rest are blank

Comment: @Hanu. . . You have put all possible filter criteria with `charindex()` & this would do what you want.

Comment: @YogeshSharma The OP's patterns all included an initial blank to avoid finding "Lot" in "Camelot". We still don't know about matching the beginning of a street name, e.g. "Apt" in "Apteryx".

Comment: @YogeshSharma the idea of using CROSS APPLY is nice, but tiny comment if I may: (1) You have extra "(" which should be removed after the word "values". (2) You need to add space before the text that you search as HABO mentioned. (3) Using distinct you will lost rows from the original table which include the same values. The question does not include request to clean duplicate rows. (4) This will not cover a case where in the same string you have two or more "stop string". For example a string that include both APT and LOT. **except these limitation it's nice solution**

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

This solution based on the idea of using CROSS APPLY which came from the solution provided by Yogesh Sharma, but this one cover more cases which get lost in Yogesh's solution like if we have duplicate rows in the original input, if we have several "stop strings" in the same input, and the case that no "stop point" exists.

Note! by "Stop string" I mean the text which we search like 'APT' or 'LOT' for example.

In order to examine the cases which are not covered in other solution I will add several rows which represent these cases

```
drop table if exists T
GO

create table T(txt nvarchar(MAX))
GO

insert T(txt) values 
('1111  24TH AVE APT2' ),
('1111  24TH AVE APT2' ),--duplicate
('2222 S ALLIS ST LOT 4'),
('333 JENIFER ST Unit 2' ),
('44444 JENIFER LOTST Unit 2' ),-- notice that we have both " LOT" and " Unit" in the string
('55555 JENIFERLOT LOTST s' ),
('6666 JENIFE  s' ),--no "stop point"
('6666 JENIFE  s' )--duplicate + no "stop point"
GO

select * from T
GO
```

Notice that we have duplicate rows which we do not want to lose. We have 8 rows in the source and we expect to get 8 rows in the result set

```
select 
    -- you can un-mark the next line as comment - this is only for the understganding of the solution
    -- a.[txt], aa.lens, aa.RN, 
    CASE 
        WHEN aa.lens>0 then substring(a.[txt], 0, aa.lens)
        ELSE a.[txt]
    END
from T a 
cross apply( 
    -- This will fix case that we have several "stop values" in the same string
    SELECT RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by v order by lens desc), lens
    FROM (
        values 
            (CHARINDEX(' APT' , [txt]),[txt]), 
            (CHARINDEX(' LOT' , [txt]),[txt]),
            (CHARINDEX(' Unit', [txt]),[txt])
        ) aa(lens, v)
    ) aa
where RN = 1
```